# How can I acces Ghotscript from the command line in Windows 10?

Tags: ghostscript, command-line-tool

I cannot figure out how to run Ghostscript from the command line. It is included in my path:
[image: Path details]

and I restarted my PC after I made the change. I cannot access it via the command prompt however:
[image: cmd prompt failed attempts]

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing the gswin32c.exe in C:...\bin\gswin32c.exe.

Comment: Thanks! That worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that, on Windows, the Ghostscript executable is not called gs, it is either gswin32, gswin32c, gswin64 or gswin64c, depending on whether you install the 32 or 64 bit version and want the command line or windowed version of the interactive interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem turned  out to be that in my PATH I needed to be less specific; leaving it at \bin rather than \bin\gswin32c.exe